# Почему мой Discord бот не отвечает на мою команду на серверах но отвечает в ЛС? Ещё и отвечает два раза?

Tags: python, discord, бот

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

intents = discord.Intents.default()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Бокси зашёл успешно')

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('OK')

bot.run(os.getenv('token'))
```

Comment: Какие нибудь ошибки пишет?

Comment: Попробуйте intents all поставить